# PMF of mapping successful bernoulli trials and number of trials

Tags: probability, random-variables

To model a successful Bernoulli trial within n trials in an experiment of flipping coins, we have probability mass function:
$p_X(n) = (1-p)^{n-1}p, n =1,2,...$

How do we express the PMF that can model n trials for seeing $s$ successful Bernoulli trials?

My attempt:
When I think of n = 4 and s = 2, which means 4 trials and 2 success, i.e. $4C2$ .We would have 6. It seems that it relates to some sort of binomial distribution but I don't know how to associate them.

Comment: Is this what you're looking for? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_binomial_distribution

Comment: Exactly! I appreciate it. The PMF of negative binomial distribution is the exact answer of modeling $s$ success in $n$ trials. As the wikipedia link suggested, we should use $r$ instead of $s$ representing the specified number of successes.